# BLE write private characteristic to UUID

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller

I use a RN4020 BLE Module to communicate with the VALRT BT Button: https://vsnmobil.com/products/v-alrt/specs

Problem is, I need to send "80BEF5ACFF" within 30sec after connect to the specific private UDID "FFFFFFF5-00F7-4000-B000-000000000000" (see reference: https://github.com/HoyosIntegrity/V.ALRT-bluetooth-spec)

Problem is, I always get "ERR" back from RN4020.

Here is my Initialisation Code (which works):

```
sf,2 //Factory Reset
+ //echo on
sr,92000000 //configure as Master
r,1 //reboot
F //search devices
X //stop searching
E,0,001EC026C931 //connect to device with mac: 001EC026C931 which is my device 
B //Bond
```

Get a "Connected" back and the Button quit it with a Beep.

Now I tried to Write

```
CUWV,FFFFFFF5-00F7-4000-B000-000000000000,80BEF5ACFF
```

with and without "-" but allways get a error back. At github are samples for Android and iOS but its not clear for me what I have to send...

Think I forgotten a prestep, but I dont know which one.

Answer (score 0):

Strange is, when I connect and send "LC" I get this back:

```
    180A

  2A23,0012,02

  2A24,0014,02

  2A25,0016,02

  2A26,0018,02

  2A27,001A,02

  2A28,001C,02

  2A29,001E,02

  2A2A,0020,02

1803

  2A06,0025,0A

1802

  2A06,0028,04

1804

  2A07,002B,02

  2A07,002C,10

180F

  2A19,002F,02

  2A19,0030,10

  FFFFFFA000F74000B000000000000000

  FFFFFFA100F74000B000000000000000,0034,0A

  FFFFFFA200F74000B000000000000000,0037,02

  FFFFFFA300F74000B000000000000000,003A,00

  FFFFFFA300F74000B000000000000000,003B,10

  FFFFFFA400F74000B000000000000000,003E,00

  FFFFFFA400F74000B000000000000000,003F,10

  FFFFFFA500F74000B000000000000000,0042,00

  FFFFFFA500F74000B000000000000000,0043,10

END
```

That are some of the services but not all.